# Do things correspond to carvings of reality?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology

I have found many papers about “carving reality at its joints” but all of them discussed carving reality into *kinds*, supposed to cluster things, themselves always considered as already given. Though I tried, I did not find papers about carving reality into *things* (individuals, particulars, entities ...). Are there any references on this topic? Is it even correct in the first place to think of a thing as carving reality into “that thing” and “everything else”?

Comment: Sounds like questions in metaphysics, with a tinge of the problem of universals?

Comment: @Frank Yes for metaphysics (I added the tag) but my question is not so much related to the problem of the universals, which is more about kinds. My question is more related to the "problem of the many", though it is not restricted to "physical" things.

Comment: Philosophical Paper by David Lewis would have a lot of modern metaphysics. The first text, about the metaphysics of holes in cheese, is quite funny.

Comment: "think of a thing" is subtly different from the said thing in itself, then it certainly makes sense to carve reality into “that thing” and “everything else” insofar as in thinking...

Comment: @DoubleKnot It is not that obvious to me that it makes sense to carve reality into, for instance, “that cloud” and “everything else”, even insofar as in thinking. My second question is more about whether it is correct or not to assume that “that cloud in itself” *actually* carves reality into “itself” and “everything else”.

Comment: *Carving* reality merely possible by some sculptor certainly is a metaphor only occurs during our thinking, “that cloud in itself” just does its own thing.

Comment: @DoubleKnot I did not really mean that it is the cloud itself or even anything / anyone else which would do a carving of reality. The question is whether it is correct or not to assume that that there are two clearly distinct “parts” of reality, one of which being exactly “that cloud in itself” and the other one being exactly “everything else”.

Comment: Reality in the sense of natural kind in itself is always a somewhat vaguely predicated concept expressible via any language means such as here (not to mention exact) compared to other ideal logical or axiomatic ones such as one truth and sets…